# What happens if the panic level rises past 5?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

If an abduction mission pops up for say Europe, Asia, and US, I'm not worried about the US due to low panic, Russia and UK are both at 4, but China and Australia are both at 5!

Will taking the mission in Europe make them leave right then as the panic level can not rise anymore?

I have 5 satellites coming in before month 4 is over so I can straighten everything out and buy myself another month before I assault the base.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They cannot exceed five and wont. This is actually a 'tactic' in playing XCom. If you get any further missions this month, you should let the "5 panic" countries pass, since any extra panic will not be added.

Note: This does *not* apply to Terror missions; **if you skip a "terror" mission the targeted country will leave the program right then and there.**